# Getting Started: Browser Remote Control Car

Tags: gpio, tutorial

I'm planning to start a project that involves:

raspi - web socket - smartphones - remote control car.

I have basic knowledge of python but i'm not sure where and how to begin this project especially when it comes to the controlling GPIO of the Raspi.

So far i have already successfully loaded up Raspbian as OS.
Some guides and pointers on links, tutorials or books for recommendations would be great. FYI, i would prefer to do the project based on Python if its possible.

Thank you.

Comment: please, be more specific about your intended use for Raspberry Pi. read the manual for python GPIO library (google it) and tell us what have you tried and what did not work as intended. maybe then someone will be able to help.